# VMware Player black screen

Tags: lubuntu, vmware-player

I installed guest lubuntu 14.10 as a VM on VMware Player 6.0.4 and installed the tools as well. If I lock my host machine (sadly Windows 7) and log in again or leave it idle for a while. lubuntu desktop goes black and hangs. The only way to use the machine is to kill vmware player then start it again. Any ideas?